# Maintaining order of linked list insertion

Tags: java, list, insertion-order

So I am making a linked list and in my insertion, I need to maintain its order. So if I were to traverse through the linked list from the root to its trail with this insertion 
-->

```
Insertion: 1 2 3
```

It should output -->

```
Output: 1 2 3
```

So far I have this code below. All this code does is output my insertion in reverse. So it prints ->

```
3
2
1
```

I want the program to maintain its insertion order by modifying my addLast() method. So when I print my Linked List it comes out the same way I inserted it.

```
public class LinkedListMeth 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     FirstLinkedList list = new FirstLinkedList();
     list.addLast(1);
     list.addLast(2);
     list.addLast(3);
     list.traverseLast();
 }
}

class FirstLinkedList
{
private class Node           
   {
      private Node next;
      private int data;
   }

   private Node last = null; 

  public void addLast(int d)
   {
       Node newNode = new Node();
       newNode.data = d;
       newNode.next = last;
       last = newNode;  
   }

    public void traverseLast()
   {
       Node head = last;
       while (head != null)

       {
           System.out.println(head.data);
           head = head.next;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I want to modify addLast() so that it prints the way I inserted the values

Comment: Field `last` references the **last** element, and the `next` field references the element **before** that (which used to be "last"), so when you print the elements in navigation order, you print "last", "second last", "third last", ..., "first", i.e. in reverse order, so why are you confused that print order is reversed? You should re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your exact current design, then one option to print the list in start-to-finish order would be to use recursion, something like this:

```
public void printFirstLinkedList(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return;

    printFirstLinkedList(node.next);

    System.out.print(node.data + " ");

    return;
}

printFirstLinkedList(yourList.last);
```

Comment: I don't want to change the way I traverse through the linked list. I want to change the    addLast() to maintain insertion order

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  If you want to maintain a head pointer, then you will have to walk down the entire list to make each insert.  If you want to maintain a tail pointer (which you are currently doing), then inserts become `O(1)`, but then things like printing the list require more work.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep root of your linked list for traversing in insert order.

Here is an edited version of your code:

```
class FirstLinkedList {
    private class Node {
        private Node next;
        private int data;
    }

    private Node root = null;
    private Node last = null;

    public void addLast(int d) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = d;
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            root.next = last;
            last = root;
        } else {
            last.next = node;
            last = last.next;
        }
    }

    public void traverseLast() {
        Node head = root;
        while (head != null) {
            System.out.println(head.data);
            head = head.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
1
2
3
```